# Java: What does this for-loop do?

Tags: java, android

```
for (String key : output.keySet())
{
       // some code
}
```

Output is an object of hashmap and I want to iterate through the hashmap for all values. I find an example on the internet that write such for loop... But when I try to execute this, Eclipse does not allow me to do so. Please tell me an efficient way or explain this loop. So that I can iterate through the map.

Pseudo of my function is somewhat like this

```
public void function (String key)
{
     Set<String> keys = output.keySet();

    // now I have to iterate through the keySet and match 'key' with the keys from keySet 
}
```

Comment: When you say "eclipse does not allow me to do so" - presumably there's an error? Tell us what it is. What is the type of `output`?

Comment: @Usama Oh come on, Eclipse definitely allows me to do this. Surely, you have a project using a Java 1.4 target for compilation.

Comment: What's the error eclipse is throwing?? and What do you want in the result?? Key? Value?

Comment: I bet it is a NullPointerException. :D

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux - never seen eclipse *predicting* NPE - would be a really great new feature ;-)  (I thought, he saw a compile error)

Comment: @Andreas_D: But the NPE appears in the Console of Eclipse... :D

Comment: @Usama Sarwar. See my answer, you don't want to iterate over the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [Java enhanced for loop.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), it was added in Java 5, so you need to use compiler settings for Java 5 or Java 6 in order to compile that loop.

Edit: I don't understand what you mean by this:

`// now i have to iterate through the keySet and match 'key' with the keys from keySet`

A map has unique keys (A set does also only contain unique values), the key can only match one key, and you can check if a key exists by doing this:

`map.contains(key);`

You can get the associated value by doing this:

`Object value = map.get(key);`

Comment: ... if *that* was the case, then eclipse "wouldn't allow" him to use generics too ...

Comment: True, but it's possible that he has a compilation error on that line too :) Hm, it sounds like he's barking up the wrong tree, he doesn't want to iterate over the keys to see if a key match. He has the key in his hand unless there's something that I don't understand.

Comment: @Kaj...my key is passed as a parameter to ythe fuction and i have to match that parameter key with the keys in keyset...and on matching i have to get value..!!!

Comment: @Usama - really? -> **Aaaaargh**. Simply use `map.get(key)` to get the value for a key, **don't** iterate on the entiry key set!!

Comment: @Usama Sarwar. I told you, just invoke `map.get(key)`, it does exactly what you need, and is a lot faster than iterating over all keys. You are using the map in the worst possible way if you decide to iterate the keys in order to find a certain key.

Comment: @ Kaj .... @ andreas ..So nice of both of you....i was just mingling the concepts...now its all clear...thanks again..!!!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a piece of code that compiles with Java 1.5+. It uses *generics* and the *enhanced for loop*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<String, String>();
  output.put("1", "one");
  output.put("2", "two");
  output.put("3", "three");

  for (String key:output.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(output.get(key));
  }
}
```

Please compare it with your own code. You tagged your question with "android" so I expect that you target Java6 source level. Please comment in detail, if that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It does one iteration for every object in `output.keyset()`, in this case `keySet` is a collection of *strings* so, for each *String* key within the collection `output.keySet()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this

Here's your map

```
Map<Something,SomeoneFun> myMap = new HashMap<Something,Someonefun);
```

if you just want to iterate the keys:

```
    for (Something myThing : MyMap.keySet() ) {
    // do whatever you want with my thing 
}
```

If you want to iterate the entries:

```
for (Entry<Something,Someone> myEntry : myMap.entrySet() ) {
          Something myKey=myEntry.getKey();
          Someone myValue = myEntry.getValue();
}
```

As noted by others, you must be running a JRE 1.5+ and targeting Java 1.5+

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get both, values

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...;
```

here is the loop,

```
  for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) 
    {    
     String key = entry.getKey();    
     Object value = entry.getValue();  
       // ...
     }
```